# How to make a basic HTML form submit work even in angular 4 environment?

Tags: html, angular, forms

I am new to Angular 2+ and having trouble in basic form submit. 
Though I am using Angular, I want to know how I can just submit a form using submit button. The Trivial way of submission.

```
<form action="/api/profile/me" method="post">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Even after clicking the submit button I cannot see browser trying to communicate with the server.

How can I make angular not to listen to this specific form events?

Thank you all.

Comment: You can submit without angular. Set action attribute on form tag and add named inputs into it. Should work.

Comment: <form action="/api/profile/me" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="profileImage">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
I did the above. But still its submit is not working.

Thanks @tano

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways to create a form in angular

you may go with reactive forms and follow this nice tuttorial

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-forms-in-angular-4-reactive-forms--cms-29787

```
    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(profile)" [formGroup]="profile">
     <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
// add your coustome message here
 </form>
```

and in the component ts file

```
 this.profile = this.fb.group({
      email: [null, [Validators.required]]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I am trying is not to use Angular ways of submitting. I want to submit it without Angular ways. Just HTML form submit.

Comment: you may do anything you want it is recommended technique and uses best approaches if you look for another alternative then you have suffer with validation part and if you are putting input type submit then anyhow you have to go with form (ngSubmit)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Reactive Forms.

First, add ReactiveFormsModule into the app.module.ts.

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LoginRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

Then, add form tag into the app.componenet.html.

```
<form [formGroup]="rForm" (ngSubmit)="addPost(rForm.value)">
        <input type="text" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email">
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!rForm.valid">LOGIN</button>
 </form>
```

and the last app.componenet.ts file should look like this:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  rForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.rForm = fb.group({
  'email': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])] });
    }
   addPost(post) {
    console.log(post);
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am not in search of solutions based on Angular.

Comment: Simply add the action to the form tag.<form action="">
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>